# java moulde.info desktop objectbox

Tags: java, java-11, module-info, objectbox-java

I am having an issue setting up the module.info file for my java desktop app, I am using object box desktop as a database, so I am stuck at this error, I am using maven.

```bash
java: the unnamed module reads package io.objectbox.converter from both objectbox.java and objectbox.java.api
```

at times after edits I get a similar error

```bash
java: the com.app module reads package io.objectbox.converter from both objectbox.java and objectbox.java.api
```

so I an stuck in what may seems to be a loop  .

Comment: developers from objectbox needs to ensure they clean up split packages for you to be able to use it in a modular application

Comment: It doesn't look like that library has been modularized. And if they have two separate JAR files with the same package, then you can't load them as named modules (JPMS does not allow split packages). There seems to be an open issue about this: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/840

Comment: Until the library is fixed, make your app non modular.  Delete the module-info.java from your app and follow the instructions and command line switches for non modular JavaFX apps at openjfx.io.  Ensure that only JavaFX modules are on the module path and that the objectbox library is only on the classpath.

Comment: thanks to all and fully noted.